# Mat-checkbox :- On click it selects all

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat-checkbox here. When I select one checkbox it automatically selects all the checkbox. What I am doing wrong here? is this the way it supposed to work?

[stackblitz code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcrcp7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

What I want is on click it should check that particular checkbox. Clicking on already checked checkbox it should uncheck.

Comment: youre double binding all checkbox to the same variable therefore setting them all to fix u can make checked an array and double bind to checked[index] u can get the index by rewriting your ngFor to :"let list of lists;let index=index"

Comment: @jonathanHeindl can you please help me with the code?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjhvhb

Comment: It worked. You can add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: It will be good if you add the stackblitz link also with the answer.

Comment: Can any one tell me why the question is downvoted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre double binding all checkbox to the same variable therefore setting them all to fix u can make checked an array and double bind to checked[index] u can get the index by rewriting your ngFor to :"let list of lists;let index=index"